# Saving and opening a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have created and saved a dataset which looks like this:

```
# line 1
foo+++$+++faa+++$+++fee
# +++$+++ is the separator
```

I've saved like a `.txt` and then saved to `tf` with

```
from tensorflow.data import TextLineDataset
from tensorflow.data.experimental import save, load
tfsaved = TextLineDataset('path_to_file.txt')
save(tfsaved, 'path_tf_dataset')
```

But, when I load the dataset, it looks like this:

```
# Line 1
foofaafee
```

Can I, in any way, show to `tf` that `+++$+++` is my separator? If not, how can I solve this?

Comment: What exactly is your goal with this dataset? Or are you just experimenting with `TextLineDataset`?

Comment: @AloneTogether my goal is to have 3 features in one dataset. i've used `textLineDataset` because is the only way I know, maybe there is other better!

Comment: Are you creating the dataset yourself? If you are, you can just use a dataframe and use whatever delimiter you want..

Comment: @AloneTogether but how could I pass to a `tf.Dataset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how you can read your data using `pandas` and pass it to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`:

data.csv

```
feature1+++$+++feature2+++$+++feature3
foo+++$+++faa+++$+++fee
foo+++$+++faa+++$+++fee
foo+++$+++faa+++$+++fee
foo+++$+++faa+++$+++fee
foo+++$+++faa+++$+++fee
foo+++$+++faa+++$+++fee
foo+++$+++faa+++$+++fee
```

```py
import pandas as pd 
import tensorflow as tf

df =  pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\+\+\+\$\+\+\+', engine='python')
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df)))

for d in ds.take(3):
  tf.print(d)
```

```
{'feature1': "foo", 'feature2': "faa", 'feature3': "fee"}
{'feature1': "foo", 'feature2': "faa", 'feature3': "fee"}
{'feature1': "foo", 'feature2': "faa", 'feature3': "fee"}
```

Note that I had to escape the characters `+` and `$`, since they are special regex characters.